# How to in JS find in an array of objects two objects with one same key/value but output the one has anotehr key/value higher

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to extract from an array of objects one specific object which has one value higher than another object.

The particularity is that I can have multiple objects and I need to find 2 or more which have the same key/value called `role: GUARDIAN` and then extract the one which has a higher value on the key `signOrder.

An array example

```
[
   {
     ....
     signOrder: 1,
     role: 'CONSENTEE',
   },
   {
     signOrder: 2,
     role: 'GUARDIAN',
   },
   {
     role: 'GUARDIAN',
     signOrder: 3
   }
 ]
```

**Cases**

1. I'm getting an array-like above but there is only one guardian so I'm extracting only that guardian information
2. I'm getting 2 guardians as above and need to extract the guardian with the highest number signOrder = 3

what will be the best way to do this in the right way to have the output of the 2 points above as

Output 1 I have only one guardian so I take that one

```
{
 role: 'GUARDIAN',
 signOrder: 2
}
```

Output 2 I have multiple Guardians so I take the one with the highest `signOrder`

```
{
 role: 'GUARDIAN',
 signOrder: 3
}
```

Comment: I was trying an approach with a reducer but missing the thing of the role itself 

```
let signOrder = recipientsOrder.reduce((max, recipient) =>
        max.signOrder > recipient.signOrder
          ? max.signOrder
          : recipient.signOrder
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const roles = [
 {
   signOrder: 1,
   role: 'CONSENTEE',
 },
 {
   signOrder: 2,
   role: 'GUARDIAN',
 },
 {
   role: 'GUARDIAN',
   signOrder: 3
 }
];
 
const getHighestByRole = (roles, roleToFind) => {
  // Get all objects for given role
  const foundRoles = roles.filter(({ role }) => role === roleToFind);
  // Sort them by `signOrder` then return first item
  return foundRoles.sort((a, b) => b.signOrder - a.signOrder)[0];
}

console.log(getHighestByRole(roles, 'GUARDIAN'));
console.log(getHighestByRole(roles, 'CONSENTEE'));
```